# how to change animation speed in turn.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, turnjs

I have a project which is e-catalog. I have used turn.js library for it. It was a great library and i would like to change something like the animation speed when turning into pages. But there is no option, properties or method built in turn.js to modify it. anyone can help? or at least tell what part of the code it is located to change the speed? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find your solution?!

Answer (score 3):

you can set the animation duration when initializing the book.

here's the doc : http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Option:_duration

and how to use it :

```
book.turn({ // init
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    duration : 1300
});
```